# jsoup.Parse not working on iframe element

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to parse HTML file. The HTML includes iframe contents. But jsoup.parse() is working on all elements excepts iframe elements. Can anyone help me on this.
For example:

```
String html = "<iframe src='demo_iframe.htm' height='200' width='300'></iframe>";
String doc = Jsoup.parse(html).text();
System.out.println(doc);

The output should look like:
```

demo_iframe.htm height:200 width:200

Comment: your html String value should be like this "<iframe src='demo_iframe.htm' height='200' width='300'></iframe>"

Comment: okay. that was typo error. Is there a way we could parse that iframe content? @Alice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select `iframe` element. Here is solution

```
String html = "<iframe src='demo_iframe.htm' height='200' width='300'></iframe>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element iframe = doc.select("iframe").first();
    String iframeSrc = iframe.attr("src");
    String height = iframe.attr("height");
    String width = iframe.attr("width");
    System.out.println(iframeSrc + " height:" + height + " width:" + width);
```

[Use selector-syntax to find elements](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: What if we use h1 or any other tag included with it iframe. for instance: Striing html =  "<iframe src='demo_iframe.htm' height='200' width='300'></iframe> <h1> Welcome Hello World </h1>";

Comment: Do you mean <h1> tag inside <iframe> tag? Please refer to answer link for how to use selector.